# Do I need a subquery when doing DISTRIBUTE BY in a UNION query?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Consider:

```sql
select 1 as id, 2 as val

UNION ALL

select 2 as id, 1 as val

DISTRIBUTE BY id SORT BY val
```

It's a bit ambiguous whether `DISTRIBUTE BY` applies only to the second `select` table, or if it applies to the result of `UNION ALL`.

Do I need a subquery to ensure the `DISTRIBUTE` step is applied only *after* `UNION ALL` is done, i.e.

```sql
select * from (
  select 1 as id, 2 as val
  union all
  select 2 as id, 1 as val
)
DISTRIBUTE BY id SORT BY val
```

The `EXPLAIN` of both queries looks the same:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Sort [val#636 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#635, 200)
   +- Union
      :- *(1) Project [1 AS id#635, 2 AS val#636]
      :  +- Scan OneRowRelation[]
      +- *(2) Project [2 AS id#637, 1 AS val#638]
         +- Scan OneRowRelation[]
```

But I'm not clear this is always the case for more complicated queries (there was a small difference in column alias `#` of one column in a more practical use case I tried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Hive docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Union):

> To apply ORDER BY, SORT BY, CLUSTER BY, DISTRIBUTE BY or LIMIT to an
> individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that
> enclose the SELECT:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT key FROM (SELECT key FROM src ORDER BY key LIMIT 10) subq1 
> UNION
> SELECT key FROM (SELECT key FROM src1 ORDER BY key LIMIT 10) subq2
> ```
>
> To apply an ORDER BY, SORT BY, CLUSTER BY, DISTRIBUTE BY or LIMIT
> clause to the entire UNION result, place the ORDER BY, SORT BY,
> CLUSTER BY, DISTRIBUTE BY or LIMIT after the last one.
>
> The following
> example uses both ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT key FROM src
> UNION 
> SELECT key FROM src1  
> ORDER BY key LIMIT 10
> ```

So in your case the DISTRIBUTE BY clause will be applied to the whole result of UNION.